# Add custom headers to ViewEngine response pages in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-razor

I am using [ServiceStack](https://www.servicestack.com) with [SharpPages](https://sharpscript.net/) to render dynamic content.  For "reasons", I need to set the CORS headers `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`, supporting multiple subdomains.

My SharpPages feature is enabled with :

```
var pagesFeature = new SharpPagesFeature()
        {
            ScriptMethods = { new UrlScriptMethods(), new DbScriptsAsync() },
        };
        pagesFeature.Args[ServiceStack.Script.ScriptConstants.DefaultDateFormat] = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm";
        pagesFeature.Args[ServiceStack.Script.ScriptConstants.DefaultDateTimeFormat] = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm";
        Plugins.Add(pagesFeature);
```

I'm hosting on IIS, so I could use web.config like below, but I can only specify one domain this way.  If I specify multiple, `XMLHttpRequest` calls complain there are multiple domains set for that header.

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://subdomain.domain.com" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Likewise, I could have used the ServiceStack `HostConfig` property `GlobalResponseHeaders`, but same deal.

I've even tried ServiceStack `PreRequestFilters`, but those aren't called unless a service method is called.  Here is my filter:

```
this.PreRequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp) =>
        {
            var origin = httpReq.Headers.Get(HttpHeaders.Origin);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(origin))
            {
                httpResp.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.AllowOrigin, origin);
                httpResp.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.AllowCredentials, "true");
            }
        });
```

Finally, `StaticFileHandler.ResponseFilter` won't work, since I'm using a view engine and not static files.

So, how can I add custom response headers to View Pages (SharpPages in particular, possibly Razor pages as well) in `ServiceStack`?

The raw request is below.  Interesting that I'm requesting `https://computer.domain` but FireFox translates that to `localhost`.  Regardless, the `favicon.ico` request DOES get trapped by the filter.  The request below DOES NOT.

```
GET /forms/newsletter HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44308
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: ss-pid=wCR4INmjLXpBnbsBoe2n
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

The raw response is :

```
HTTP/2.0 200 OK
cache-control: private
content-type: text/html
content-encoding: gzip
vary: Accept-Encoding
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319
x-sourcefiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcamtsZW1tYWNrXFNvdXJjZVxSZXBvc1xPQlJDX0JNU1xCTVMuV2ViLkJvdHRsZURyb3BDZW50ZXJzXEJNUy5XZWIuQm90dGxlRHJvcENlbnRlcnNcZm9ybXNcbmV3c2xldHRlcg==?=
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
access-control-allow-origin: *
date: Tue, 11 Jun 2019 16:28:34 GMT
content-length: 862
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

Comment: `PreRequestFilters` should be called for all ServiceStack requests, which Sharp Pages request doesn't call the `PreRequestFilters`?

Comment: @mythz  I've added my SharpPages feature call & the pre-request filter to the question above.  Local site is hosted via internal network name (`http://computer.domain`).  I created a 2nd local site hosted on 127.0.0.1, and am loading the SharpPage via `$.ajax({ crossDomain: true, ...})` on page load.   The `PreRequestFilter` is not hit at all from the, XMLHttpRequest, but the SharpPage is being returned.  Using Chrome & FireFox with caching disabled via DevTools.

Comment: Is this a content page or a view page (I.e in response to a Service)? I’ve tested that content pages do call the filter. Are you testing whether the filter gets called in a debugger?

Comment: Content page - no backing Service.  I have the debugger set on the filter and it's not tripping.  Even added logging in case of wonky VS debugger and still nada.  It *does* trip when I navigate directly from the browser, but DOES NOT when I load via $.ajax.  I added in a cache breaker (?t= [date time ticks]) - no different.   Why would SS treat an ajax call differently?

Comment: Can you post the raw HTTP Request/Response Headers? Also include {{now}} in your page so you can verify a cached response isn’t being returned.

Comment: Posted above.  As I mentioned, the `favicon.ico` gets stopped.  The `forms/newsletter` does not.

Comment: There’s no indication that request is being handled by ServiceStack? Is this a Sharp Page that’s being rendered or a static .html file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194774/discussion-between-jklemmack-and-mythz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PreRequestFilters` should now be fired for all Razor and [Sharp Pages](https://sharpscript.net/docs/sharp-pages) requests from the latest v5.5.1+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: ServiceStack is worth every penny of our commercial licenses.  Thanks @mythz!

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I've created a portmanteau.  For a particular sub-folder, I'm using web.config to allow all remote origins.  For Service-based calls, I'm using a hand-rolled version of `CorsFeature` (a small amount of custom logic won't work).

```
<location path="views/subfolder">  <-- applies the ACAO header for specific view pages
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```